# Why does calling list() on iterable change it?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

Consider this code, wherein I use `combinations` and attempt to make a list out of them.

```
from itertools import combinations

t = (1,2,3,4)
print("t is %r" % (t,))
print("list(t) is %r" % list(t))
print("list(t) is %r" % list(t))

t2 = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
print("t2 is %r" % (t2,))

combs = combinations(t2, 2)
print("List of combinations of t2: %r" % list(combs))
print("List of combinations of t2: %r" % list(combs))
```

The output is (unexpectedly for me)

```
t is (1, 2, 3, 4)
list(t) is [1, 2, 3, 4]
list(t) is [1, 2, 3, 4]
t2 is ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
List of combinations of t2: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
List of combinations of t2: []
```

So clearly, `list()` has side-effects.
As expected, converting a tuple to a list does not change the original data, I can do it multiple times. But when I try the same with an iterable returned from `combinations`, this works only once and then the iterable is seemingly invalid. Does `list` call `next` on the iterable so that after it is done, the iterator is at the end or why does this happen?
And how can I avoid it?

Comment: `combinations` is a generator function, which you can only iterate over once. Calling `list` on it exhausts it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.combinations` produces a lazy generator, not a complete data structure that gets saved in memory. Once you exhaust it (iterate through it) with something like `list()`, it is... well, exhausted. Empty. If you want to use it repeatedly, save a reference:

```
combs = list(combinations(t2, 2))
print("List of combinations of t2: %r" % combs)
print("List of combinations of t2: %r" % combs)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly observed, `list` is destructive, as a generator can only be exhausted once. A simple solution is to use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
>>> c1, c2 = itertools.tee(itertools.combinations(["a", "b", "c"], 2))
>>> print(list(c1))
... will print the entire sequence of combinations
>>> print(list(c2))
... same as before
```

This may be more memory-conservative as holding on to the entire list, as `itertools.tee` only needs to hold on to the elements that have not been consumed by all iterators.